# python importlib seems to be sharing data between instances

Tags: python, file, parallel-processing, houdini

Ok, so I am having a weird one.  I am running python in a SideFX Hython (their custom build) implementation that is using [PDG](https://www.sidefx.com/products/pdg/).  The only real difference between Hython and vanilla Python is some internal functions for handling geometry data and compiled nodes, which shouldn't be an issue even though they are being used.

The way the code runs, I am generating a list of files from the disk which creates PDG work items.  Those work items are then processed in parallel by PDG.  Here is the code for that:

```py
import importlib.util
import pdg
import os
from pdg.processor import PyProcessor
import json

class CustomProcessor(PyProcessor):
    def __init__(self, node):
        PyProcessor.__init__(self,node)
        self.extractor_module = 'GeoExtractor'

    def onGenerate(self, item_holder, upstream_items, generation_type):
        for upstream_item in upstream_items:
            new_item = item_holder.addWorkItem(parent=upstream_item, inProcess=True)
        return pdg.result.Success
    
    def onCookTask(self, work_item):
        spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("callback", "Geo2Custom.py")
        GE = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
        spec.loader.exec_module(GE)
        GE.convert(f"{work_item.attribValue('directory')}/{work_item.attribValue('filename')}{work_item.attribValue('extension')}", work_item.index, f'FRAME { work_item.index }', self.extractor_module)
        return pdg.result.Success

def bulk_convert (path_pattern, extractor_module = 'GeoExtractor'):
    type_registry = pdg.TypeRegistry.types()
    try:
        type_registry.registerNode(CustomProcessor, pdg.nodeType.Processor, name="customprocessor", label="Custom Processor", category="Custom")
    except Exception:
        pass
    whereItWorks = pdg.GraphContext("testBed")
    whatWorks    = whereItWorks.addScheduler("localscheduler")
    whatWorks.setWorkingDir(os.getcwd (), '$HIP')
    
    whereItWorks.setValues(f'{whatWorks.name}', {'maxprocsmenu':-1, 'tempdirmenu':0, 'verbose':1})
    
    findem       = whereItWorks.addNode("filepattern")
    whereItWorks.setValue(f'{findem.name}', 'pattern', path_pattern, 0)
    
    generic      = whereItWorks.addNode("genericgenerator")
    whereItWorks.setValue(generic.name, 'itemcount', 4, 0)
     
    custom       = whereItWorks.addNode("customprocessor")
    custom.extractor_module = extractor_module
    node1 = [findem]
    node2 = [custom]*len(node1)
    
    for n1, n2 in zip(node1, node2):
        whereItWorks.connect(f'{n1.name}.output', f'{n2.name}.input')
        n2.cook(True)
        for node in whereItWorks.graph.nodes():
            node.dirty(False)
        whereItWorks.disconnect(f'{n1.name}.output', f'{n2.name}.input')
    
    print ("FULLY DONE")
```

```py
import os
import hou
import traceback

import CustomWriter
import importlib

def convert (filename, frame_id, marker, extractor_module = 'GeoExtractor'):
    Extractor = importlib.__import__ (extractor_module)
    base, ext = os.path.splitext (filename)
    if ext == '.sc':
        base = os.path.splitext (base)[0]
    dest_file = base + ".custom"

    geo = hou.Geometry ()
    geo.loadFromFile (filename)
    try:
        frame = Extractor.extract_geometry (geo, frame_id)
    except Exception as e:
        print (f'F{ frame_id } Geometry extraction failed: { traceback.format_exc () }.')
        return None

    print (f'F{ frame_id } Geometry extracted. Writing file { dest_file }.')
    try:
        CustomWriter.write_frame (frame, dest_file)
    except Exception as e:
        print (f'F{ frame_id } writing failed: { e }.')

    print (marker + " SUCCESS")
```

The onCookTask code is run when the work item is processed.

Inside of the GeoExtractor.py program I am importing the geometry file defined by the work item, then converting it into a couple Pandas dataframes to collate and process the massive volumes of data quickly, which is then passed to a custom set of functions for writing binary files to disk from the Pandas data.

Everything appears to run flawlessly, until I check my output binaries and see that they escalate in file size much more than they should, indicating that either something is being shared between instances or not cleared from memory and subsequent loads of the extractor code is appending the dataframes which are named the same.

I have run the GeoExtractor code sequentially with the python instance closing between each file conversion using the exact same code and the files are fine, growing only very slowly as the geometry data volume grows, so the issue has to lie somewhere in the parallelization of it using PDG and calling the GeoExtractor.py code over and over for each work item.

I have contemplated moving the importlib stuff to the `__init__()` for the class leaving only the call to the member function in the `onCookTask()` function.  Maybe even going so far as to pass a unique variable for each work item which is used inside GeoExtractor to create a closure of the internal functions so they are unique instances in memory.

I tried to do a stripped down version of GeoExtractor and since I'm not sure where the leak is, I just ended up pulling out comments with proprietary or superfluous information and changing some custom library names, but the file ended up kinda long so I am including a pastebin: https://pastebin.com/4HHS8D2W

As for CustomGeometry and CustomWriter, there is no working form of either of those libraries that will be NDA safe, so unfortunately they have to stay blackboxed.  The CustomGeometry is a handful of container classes which organize all of the data coming out of the geometry, and the writer is a formatter/writer for the binary format we are utilizing.  I am hoping the issue wouldn't be in either of them.

`Edit 1:` I fixed an issue in the example code.
`Edit 2:` Added larger examples.

Comment: It's really rather hard to help without seeing _any_ of GeoExtractor, but that sounds like you're possibly confusing class-level attributes with instance attributes in there? Also, the example code you have is referring to a `this.GE`, yet you assign to a local  `GE` – is that on purpose..?

Comment: For the this.GE issue I have actually moved the stuff to `__init__()` already, but it is untested.  I wanted to ask about it here first.  I'll fix that here.  I will try to see what I can sanitize of NDA materials from the geo extractor code.  Essentially it is just making a dataframe, filtering it based on what is needed for the binary writing, then organizing it for the writing component.  I have a couple of things to do at this exact moment, so it will be an hour or two before I can do that.

Comment: Your debugging task, at this point, is to write a very simple toy GE.PDGCallback, not under NDA, which consumes resources similarly to the target code of interest. Often doing that will reveal to you what's happening with the more complex hard-to-debug original code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: nit: Take advantage of flake8. It would have told you that instead of the phrasing `".\Geo..."`, it's better to write a raw r-string `r".\Geo..."`. One day you'll try to run "\test_geo..." and chaos will ensue. Or you might prefer to change the meaning, writing "./Geo..." instead. Tinier nit: Your ctor is just fine, but nowadays we prefer to write: `super().__init__(self, node)`

Comment: @J_H The init in the code that was quoted above originally is defined in the PDG software I am utilizing, so I cannot deviate from their definitions too much for fear of breaking their systems.  I will keep it in mind for my own code in the future though.

Comment: @AKX I have updated the code and been able to include examples.  Hopefully they help.

Comment: @Adalast Well, at a quick glance the culprit now could be `CustomGeometry.Frame` – if instances of that class (at least I assume it's a class) end up sharing a single `constructs` object...

Comment: @AKX I think they might.  It is, in fact, a class and could be the culprit if the individual instances are not being created on each thread (work item) in isolation.  Now I just need to figure out a good way to isolate them.

Comment: @Adalast It sounds like a classic `class Frame: constructs = [] ... def __init__...` oopsie.

Comment: @AKX The code for that has `constructs` in `def __init__():` as `self.constructs = []`.  Is that still going to have the issue?

Comment: No, that would be fine.

Comment: @AKX Lol, thanks, glad we got it right.  Now I still need to figure out what is going on.  I am just going to have to dump all of my dataframes from each work item and see what is actually building up.  I was wanting to avoid doing that as it is going to be a LOT of data, but it might just be what is up.